# Generating a password with case sensitivity criteria

Tags: python

I have been working on some code to generate a password. I'm using some cool things like random length (defined by a range), some uppercase and lowercase chars and also digits. I want to now make a little ruleset:

- a password must always contain at least one digit,   one uppercase   letter  and one lower case letter,
- adjacent chars are not the same.

Here's my code for the generator and its rules:

```
import random
length==random.randint(7,14)
ListOfChars=[]
    codes=list(range(48,57))+list(range(65,90))+list(range(97,122))
for a in range(length):
    ASCIIcode=random.choice(codes)
    ListOfChars.append(chr(ASCIIcode))
print(''.join(ListOfChars)
```

Here you can see the ascii ranges are already defined as well as the variable length 7-14, but I can't seem to find a way to not generate the same char again, or to ensure at least 1 of each of the 3 char types.

Comment: Why can't adjacent chars be the same? How is that a good rule for a password? `"I love my passwords, they will always succeed!"` is a great password due to the long length, but it would fail by your rules because of the double letters?

Comment: @Ffisegydd hello! I am just trying to practise with experimenting with string rules in all honesty. I want to know how to not have the same thing being repeated in this instance. Thanks!

Comment: For not repeating characters just insert an extra `while ASCIIcode != previousASCIIcode` inside your `for` loop.

Comment: For the overall problem the simplest solution would be to select a random subset from each of the three character sets, concatenate the subsets, and shuffle them. The only downside is that every character would be unique which is slightly more strict that what you've specified. But given that you're generating random passwords it wouldn't really matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work nicely. It first builds a set of requirements for each entry in the password and shuffles them. It then build each entry based on that requirement and such that there are no identical consecutive entries:

```
import string

length = random.randint(7, 14)

set1 = string.ascii_uppercase                   # A-Z   
set2 = string.digits                            # 0-9
set3 = string.digits + string.ascii_letters     # a-z A-Z 0-9
build = [set1, set2] + [set3] * (length - 2)    # 1 uppercase, one digit, reset from full set
random.shuffle(build)                           # shuffle the order

password = []
index = 0
last = ''

while len(password) < length:                   # keep appending until length is reached
    choice = random.choice(build[index])
    if choice != last:
        password.append(choice)
        index += 1
        last = choice

print ''.join(password)
```

Giving results such as:

```
6ZFTauQ
c6a29MTditDJUy
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way you could approach this problem, as I suggested in a comment:

```
from string import ascii_lowercase, ascii_uppercase, digits
from random import randint, shuffle, sample

length = randint(7, 14)

length1 = randint(1, length - 2)
length2 = randint(1, length - length1 - 1)
length3 = randint(1, length - length1 - length2)

lengths = [length1, length2, length3]
shuffle(lengths)

subsets = list(map(sample, [ascii_lowercase, ascii_uppercase, digits], lengths))
result = subsets[0]
result.extend(subsets[1])
result.extend(subsets[2])
shuffle(result)
result = ''.join(result)
print(result)
```

I don't know how uniform it is, i.e. it probably biases towards some longer lengths.

Comment: Hmm. This looks very interesting and taken me quite some time to understand the code but I think I get it -- you're dividing it up into subsets. I wonder if there's just a simpler way to code a line or two along the lines of this pseudocode: if character before this one is the same as the one about to be generated, generate a new one and check again?

Comment: @MariuszAndrzejewski Yes, I was suggesting that in a comment on the question. A while loop is the typical way to do it. Think about it for a bit and if you can't see how to do it I'll show you. However this doesn't address the issue of ensuring that every kind of character is in there. This answer was my preferred way to do that.

Comment: Thanks very much for your patience. I decided to look up what a while loop is (new to concept) and have drafted this, it doesn't work however I feel I understand part of the logic now. I don't know the python code, but here's a full pseudocode for that part:

while ListOfChars -1 = ListOfChars   # If the list item before this proposed new one = the new one being generated then,

(repeat generation stage)

Comment: P.S regarding uniformity of the longer sets answer, it seems to generate longer lengths but  could just be me, don't think I would have noticed it without you raising it!